# Fishy or legit email from Stellar Lumen

Tags: lumens

Not sure this is the best place to ask, but I just received a weird email that got me a bit worried.
I am not planning on clicking on any button, but I was wondering if that is a legit email.
If not, is there room for concern? In other words, should I transfer my funds to a different wallet? I am using a hardware key, so I would think I am safe, but better to make sure.

[image]

Comment: That's 100% phishing email. Do not click any links there.

Comment: I got the same email today. I'll note that all the links in it go to the stellar.org website - if it's a phish, I don't understand how it works. It piqued my interest in the Stellar thing, I'm not a crypto guy, but something very strange is going on. I was given 150 lumens at the outset of stellar - I've not really done anything with it, except I created a new account and transferred 1 lumen to it just to do it. I can see that the balance of the original account is now 148.99999 lumens - I assume the 1 lumen I sent out and a .00001 lumen transaction fee. However, the account I created, and sen

Comment: @solmssen It was also "sent from" stellar. Not just spoofing the email, but with authority as if it had actually come from them. It was a very sophisticated phishing attack. I would have fallen for it had people not gotten the servers taken offline before I saw the email. Some security experts at Google were breaking it down yesterday on twitter about how well done it was.

Comment: Here's the link: https://twitter.com/FiloSottile/status/1333108901542309888

Answer (score 1):

It's a phishing scam, see the discussion at reddit.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/k3cpwe/email_from_stellarorg_this_morning_have_i_been/